# How to check if string dateformat is sortable?

Tags: python, sorting, datetime

Given a string that contains a datetime format, I want to tell the user whether it can be sorted as string or not.

For instance:

- `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` is sortable
- `'%m-%d %H:%M'` is sortable
- `'%d-%m %H:%M'` is not (28-05 will appear before 29-04 if we sort it in string)

My approach would be to parse the string and check if we follow the following order:

- Y before m before d
- H before M before S

This approach is tedious, is there an easy effective way to accomplish this ?

Comment: You could use the provided format string to convert a small precooked dataset of strings into `datetime`s and check if the sequence of the result is as expected. That would also validate the supplied format string, which even seasoned programmers have been known to get wrong.

Comment: "'%m-%d %H:%M' is sortable" provided they are all in the same year.

Comment: @tobias_k and in the same time zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is selecting only the markers that are present, then see if they are in the right order:

```
def is_sortable(format_string):
     markers = ['%Y', '%m', '%d', '%H', '%M', '%s']
     indices = [format_string.index(marker) for marker in markers if marker in format_string]
     return indices == sorted(indices)
```

If the indices are not in the right order, the string is not sortable.

```
is_sortable('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
True
is_sortable('%d-%m')
False
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

To perform the check in linear time you can create an iterator from the sequence of formatting tokens so that you can validate the order of a given formatting string by iterating through the relevant tokens in the formatting string to find the next match from the iterator using the `in` opeartor:

```
def is_sortable(format, order='YmdHMS'):
    tokens = set(order)
    seq = iter(order)
    return all(char in seq for char in format if char in tokens)

print(is_sortable('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) # True
print(is_sortable('%m-%d %H:%M'))       # True
print(is_sortable('%d-%m %H:%M'))       # False
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it following way:

```
import re
order = 'YmdHMS'
f1 = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
f2 = '%m-%d %H:%M'
f3 = '%d-%m %H:%M'
def is_sortable(x):
    elems = re.findall(r'%(\w)', x)
    return elems == sorted(elems, key=order.index)
print(is_sortable(f1))  # True
print(is_sortable(f2))  # True
print(is_sortable(f3))  # False
```

Explanation: I use regular expression to extract specifier from format string, then I compare if they preserve order when `sorted` using their position in `order` as `key`. `order` is string where near end smaller unit is therefore lower `.index` indicates bigger unit and thus using `sorted` with `key=order.index` give used units from biggest to lowest. Keep in mind that this solution will fail if there is specifier used which is absent in `order`.

Comment: Your function will fail if any letter is included in the format but not as part of the marker. For instance, the ISO format is `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%s`